# Convert Excel date to yyyymmdd format

Tags: excel, matlab

Note: There are questions asking the opposite, I am asking how to convert original Excel date that has underlying numerical value (for example, 27 May 1997 would correspond to 35577) into yyyymmdd format.

I have an Excel file where originally the dates were entered manually. Excel displays them as dates, but as you know they have a numeric underlying value. I.e., in the example I gave above, if you export this date into any other statistical software (i.e., Matlab or R), the value would be the underlying numeric counterpart.

What I need to do is to convert these "original" Excel dates into yyyymmdd format and then export them elsewhere.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
%// For demo couple of values are assumed, but these are the values 
%// that you have got from excel file
numerical_vals = [35577 ; 35579] 

date_array = datevec(numerical_vals);
date_array(:,1) = date_array(:,1)+1900;
out = datestr(date_array,'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Output -

```
out =

1997/05/27
1997/05/29
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks, Divakar.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check your date setting in your computer.
Navigate to :

> Control Panel -> Clock and Region -> Region-change date, time or
>   number formats -> Additional Settings -> Date

There change the `Short date` under `Date formats (yyyy/MM/dd)`, then apply them in both windows and click `ok`. Restart the excel and it should work!

If it still doesn't work, you can check the format cell in excel, and convert the cells into dates.
Besides, there's a function in R called as.Date(x, format, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"), which also could work.